# Getting number as Int from a key press

Tags: c#, .net, keypress, keydown

I'm trying to get an integer from the number keys on the keyboard.  For example, I want to press 5 and get the int 5.

I am using the KeyDown event and have the following:

```
    private void listBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
            int rating = (int)e.KeyValue;
    }
```

And the output that I am getting are integers from the 50-60 range.  I have tried also using e.KeyData and e.KeyCode without any luck.

Any help with this would be appreciated, I get the feeling it's something simple that I am overlooking or not understanding.

Comment: is this winforms or WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.KeyValue` returns the character code of the key pressed.

To get the actual digit you could do some character subtractions i.e.

```
int value = 0;
if (e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57)
   value = e.KeyValue - 48;
```

NB: If you're wondering where 48 and 57 come from then you may want to check out the ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

Answer (score 1):

This works.... kinda hacky...

```
Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyData.ToString()).Replace("D",""));
```